# How to configure Gradle to bypass SSL certificate validation?

Tags: java, ssl, gradle

I have a remote repository with an `https` URL and a self-signed certificate. In Maven I could set `MAVEN_OPTS` properties to bypass certificate validation. How can I achive this with gradle?

I tried modifying the file `gradle.properties` but I can’t find the exact properties:

```
systemProp.http.ssl.insecure=true
systemProp.http.ssl.allowall=true
systemProp.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

Comment: Why not simply put the certificate into the cacerts file?

Comment: Its a option but in scale it will be kind hard to configure for every person in the team.

Comment: @cshion did u find any solution for that?

Comment: I cant find any option to bypass cert validation like maven, so i had to install ssl certificate in java cacerts.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 9):

Gradle "Trust All" Plugin
This plugin was born out of necessity for a quick-and-dirty way to use a Maven repository over HTTPS with a self-signed certificate.

When working with such a repository in gradle you may get an error:

> Error transferring file: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
> unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Usual Java way to handle such scenario would be to download site certificate, import it into a keystore, and use that keystore via the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=... JVM options.

Sometimes, you just need an easier way — disable certificate validation altogether! There are many reasons not to do that, one of them being that this approach makes connections vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Consider this code a proof-of-concept and accept full responsibility that by using it you're ultimately making an informed bad decision.

Origin
The code to disable certificate validation comes from this StackOverflow answer, although there are many similar code snippets floating around the web.

Using "Trust All" Plugin
To use gradle-trust-all, build the jar file and include it in your project:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/arteme/gradle-trust-all.git
$ cd gradle-trust-all
$ gradle build
$ cp build/libs/gradle-trust-all.jar /path/to/your/project/gradle/folder/
```

Then in your project's build.gradle file add it as a buildscript dependency and activate the plugin:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files('gradle/gradle-trust-all.jar')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'trust-all'
```

That is it. Now certificate validation in gradle is disabled.

https://github.com/arteme/gradle-trust-all

Comment: anyone able to gradle build successfully? 

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle-trust-all'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultSelfResolvingDependency_Decorated@cabd095] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: I have this problem also. It seem very old plugin. Updated 2015

Comment: I had the same problem. But I was able to compile the trust-all project by changing the following in build.gradle.

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
}
Changed to

dependencies {
    implementation gradleApi()
    implementation localGroovy()
}

Comment: The approach with the trust-all plugin worked for me straight out of the box using JDK17 and gradle 7.5.1. Thanks for the hint.